# Spring Cloud Contract wrong stub for empty body

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I am migrating an old project that uses Spring-Cloud-Contract v3.0.2.

Among others we have a contract with empty body:

```
request {
    method 'POST'
    url '/x'
    body([:])
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
    }
}
```

with contracts v3.0.2 it generates:

```
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/x",
    "method" : "POST",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : {
        "matches" : "application/json.*"
      }
    },
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "equalToJson" : "{}",
      "ignoreArrayOrder" : false,
      "ignoreExtraElements" : false
    } ]
  },
```

However, with anything newer (I've checked most versions from 3.0.3, through 3.1.8 and up to 4.0.4), this section is gone.

```
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/x",
    "method" : "POST",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : {
        "matches" : "application/json.*"
      }
    }
  },
  "response" : { // cut
```

I've read through release notes of Spring Cloud 2020.0 (which introduced Contracts [v3.0.3](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#202003)) and couldn't find anything that would discuss that change.

Is such contract (for empty body case) now obsolete?
How should I rewrite this to work with either v3.1.8 or v4.0.4 of Spring Cloud Contracts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved very similar output with:

```
body(new MatchingStrategy("{}", MatchingStrategy.Type.EQUAL_TO_JSON))
```